# Which IP to use for localhost in Ubuntu virtual box- installing hadoop

Tags: virtualbox, ip, localhost, hadoop

I am trying to install hadoop single node on a Ubuntu 14 Virtual machine( on VMWare) on a windows 7 host.
One of the steps says :

6. Get IP address using:

   ```
   ifconfig
   ```

   You get xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
7. Edit `/etc/hosts` file:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/hosts
   ```

   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx localhost

which ip address should I use in localhost here? I have one ip being shown in the Ubuntu VM when I do `ifconfig` and when I do 'whats is my ip' from the windows host I get a different public IP.
Which IP should I use? Please let me know

Regards

Shuvadeep

Answer (score 1):

You should not alter the /etc/hosts file to have localhost point at a different address than the one it already points to.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` is a magic name, and EVERY computer uses this name, and its IP address of `127.0.0.1` to refer to "This computer, right here, that I'm running on". Changing the definition of `127.0.0.1 localhost` will lead you so far into the weeds that you will never come back.

Your system gets its IP address from `/etc/hosts` if it has a "static" IP address. The IP address comes from a "DHCP server" if your system is configured to use `DHCP - Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol`.

Since you are running Ubuntu "inside" a VM, it's probably using DHCP. In any case, `ifconfig` will show you the current IP address, and `/etc/hosts` contains the IP address that will be used at network startup, if a static IP is desired. So, the IP address to use is `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`, from `ifconfig`